# Why doesn't this batch script work? Reading lines from file

Tags: windows, batch-file

ok, I give up. Why doesn't this work?

```
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F %%I in (myfile.txt) do (
    echo I: %%i
    set LINE=%%i
    echo LINE: %LINE%
)
```

"echo I:" displays the lines correctly, but "echo LINE:" is empty

I have tried different variations with the same results, such as

```
    set LINE=%i
    set LINE=%i%
    set LINE=!i!
```

Obviously there is something simple I am not understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you enabled delayed expansion, so the only thing you have to do is: use it.

replace `echo LINE: %LINE%` with `echo LINE: !LINE!`

EDIT: solution without delayed extension

```
FOR /F %%I in (myfile.txt) do ( call DoIt %%I )

exit /b
:DoIt
    echo I: %1
    set LINE=%1
    echo LINE: %LINE%
goto :eof
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks. How would this look without delayed expansion? Or is delayed expansion required in this case?

Comment: @Neilw: delayed expansion is needed to use a variable inside a block. But it is possible do do the work "outside a block" with `call`. See my edit.